# How to render text on screen using PyGame?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just wrote some code that works in the commandline, so now I'd like to give it some graphics. Now, this is my very first programming project so bear with me as I try to explain the problem:

I'm using PyGame and initialised the window as follows:

```
import pygame, pygame.midi,pygame.font, random

(width, height) = (600, 400)
background = (220,220,220)

pygame.midi.init()
pygame.font.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Chord trainer")
screen.fill(background)

pygame.display.flip()
```

Then I attempt to render text (which does not give any errors):

```
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 80)
letter = myfont.render("SOME WEIRD TEST TO TRY AND GET THINGS WORKING",0,(0,0,0))
screen.blit(letter,(100,100))
```

And because I'd like to actually see my text before the program closes, I set up an infinite loop:

```
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

When I run it, I just get the grey screen I wanted, but without any sort of text, which would make me think that there's something wrong with my blit command, but I can't figure out what.

Initially I had the rendering set in a loop, but that just made the program unresponsive so I took is out for debugging. For completeness, here is that loop:

```
while True:
    # Decide on random chord
    c1 = random.choice(chords)
    # Make sure that no repitition takes place.
    if c1==c2:
        while c1==c2:
            c1=random.choice(chords)
    c2 = c1

    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 80)
    letter = myfont.render(str(c1),0,(0,0,0))
    screen.blit(letter,(100,100))

    # Listen to Midi device and search for c.
    midi_listen(inp,sorted(c1))
    score += 1
```

Comment: Hi someone replied to one of my questions about pygame.midi with with a piece of code but I failing to pass parameters in order to initialize or launch it, please I would appreciate your input here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67642570/pygame-midi-how-to-detect-simultaneous-inputs-from-a-synthesizer/67662659#67662659

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add

```
pygame.display.flip()
```

after

```
letter = myfont.render("SOME WEIRD TEST TO TRY AND GET THINGS WORKING",0,(0,0,0))
screen.blit(letter,(100,100)
```

It will update your screen and normally you will be able to see your text.